# I am trying to draw a graph in java and it does not work. I use XYPlot.class because i need to make markers too

Tags: java

```
package com.objectplanet.chart.testing;
import java.math.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.objectplanet.chart.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.objectplanet.chart.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileView;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy;//this is for the dataset
import org.jfree.chart.plot.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;

//don't mind if here is too much libraries :)




/**
 *
 * @author Luka
 */
public class Test_english {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        double data[];
data = new double[12];
data[0] = 31;
data[1] = 28;
data[2] = 31;
data[3] = 30;
data[4] = 31;
data[5] = 30;
data[6] = 31;
data[7] = 31;
data[8] = 30;
data[9] = 31;
data[10] = 30;
data[11] = 31; 
    for(int i=1; i<12; i++){
        System.out.println(data[i]); 
    }
    //We have to make a Dataset
    //show Dataset
    //then we plug Dataset to graph
    XYPlot graph=new XYPlot();
        graph.setDataset(data);//This is the problem
        graph.draw//why does this not working?
    graph.Marker//Why is this not workig?
    // We show graph and put markers
}
}
```

So i want to read data, make a graph and put markers. Then I am going to do some Gauss fit. I can read data, but i have a problem how to make dataset, make graph and do put markers. The library should be XYPlot and no else, because it puts markers too.
Regards, Luka

Comment: `graph.draw` and `graph.Marker` - what are you expecting these to do? They sound like they should be functions, but you're not calling them with `()`.

Comment: Take a look here for a good example on how to properly use XYplot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714738/xy-plotting-with-java

Comment: Thanks. That tutorial about jfreechart is very good and it helps a lot, because it tells everything about jfreechart.